# How to execute code that uses the dependency injection container, at regular intervals?

Tags: cron

Using Drupal 10 - I tried installing Ultimate Cron for D10, but it is in Alpha state and has deprecated methods that will not let it work.

This Cron needs to be executed only on a specific day and time. But the question is, how?

I have created a service that will be used to collect some data and send an email.

```
services:
  rmdrs.send_reminder_service:
    class: Drupal\rmdrs\Service\SendRMDRSService
    arguments: ['@database', '@plugin.manager.mail', '@language_manager']
```

The SendRMDRSService class:

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\rmdrs\Service;

use \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class SendRMDRSService {
  private $db;
  private $today_timestamp;

  /**
   * The mail manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface
   */
  protected $mailManager;

  /**
   * The language manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
   */
  protected $languageManager;

  public function __construct(Connection $connection, MailManagerInterface $mail_manager, LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager) {
    // Create and set a database connection
    $this->db = $connection;
    $this->today_timestamp = strtotime(date("m/d/Y"));
    $this->mailManager = $mail_manager;
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container): static {
    return new self(
      $container->get('database'),
      $container->get('plugin.manager.mail'),
      $container->get('language_manager')
    );
  }

  public function collectAndSend() {
      $due_reminders_data = $this->getDueReminderData();
      $reminders_forecast = $this->getRemindersForecast();


      $reminder_data = array(
        'total_reminders_due' => $due_reminders_data['total_reminders_due'],
        'reminders_due' => $due_reminders_data['reminders_due'],
        'reminder_forecast' => $reminders_forecast,
        'host' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
      );

      // All system mails need to specify the module and template key (mirrored
      // from hook_mail()) that the message they want to send comes from.
      $module = 'rmdrs';
      $key = 'rmdrs_cron_message';

      // Specify 'to' and 'from' addresses.
      $to = 'cyberjobesx@gmail.com';
      $from = 'cyberjobes@gmail.com';

      $build = [
        '#theme' => 'rmdrs_cron_message',
        '#cron_var' => $reminder_data,
      ];

      $params['cron_email_body'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($build);
      $language_code = $this->languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
      $send_now = TRUE;
      $result = $this->mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $language_code, $params, $from, $send_now);
  }


  private function getDueReminderData() {
    $reminder_due_data = null;
    $reminders_due_query = $this->db->select('rmdrs_schedules', 'sched');
    $reminders_due_query->join('rmdrs_reminders', 'rem', 'rem.id = sched.reminder_id');
    $reminders_due_query->join('rmdrs_categories', 'cat', 'cat.id = rem.category_id');
    $reminders_due_query->join('rmdrs_frequencies', 'freq', 'freq.frequency_code = rem.frequency');
    $reminders_due_query->addField('sched', 'id', 'schedule_id');
    $reminders_due_query->addField('rem', 'id', 'reminder_id');
    $reminders_due_query->fields('cat', ['category'])->fields('rem', ['title',])
      ->fields('sched', ['next_reminder_date', 'next_reminder_timestamp', 'reminder_id'])
      ->fields('freq', ['frequency_text'])
      ->orderBy("sched.next_reminder_timestamp", "ASC")
      ->condition('sched.active', '1')
      ->condition('sched.completed', '1', '<>')
      ->condition('sched.next_reminder_timestamp', $this->today_timestamp, '<=');

    $reminder_due_data['total_reminders_due'] = count($reminders_due_query->execute()->fetchAll());

    if ($reminder_due_data['total_reminders_due'] != 0) {
      $reminder_due_data['reminders_due'] = $reminders_due_query->range(0, 10)->execute()->fetchAll();
    } else {
      $reminder_due_data['reminders_due'] = "No Reminders due at this time";
    }

    return $reminder_due_data;
  }


  private function getRemindersForecast() {
    $reminders_forecast_query = $this->db->select('rmdrs_schedules', 'sched');
    $reminders_forecast_query->join('rmdrs_reminders', 'rem', 'rem.id = sched.reminder_id');
    $reminders_forecast_query->join('rmdrs_categories', 'cat', 'cat.id = rem.category_id');
    $reminders_forecast_query->join('rmdrs_frequencies', 'freq', 'freq.frequency_code = rem.frequency');
    $reminders_forecast_query->addField('sched', 'id', 'schedule_id');
    $reminders_forecast_query->addField('rem', 'id', 'reminder_id');
    $reminders_forecast_query->fields('cat', ['category'])->fields('rem', ['title',])
      ->fields('sched', ['next_reminder_date', 'next_reminder_timestamp', 'reminder_id'])
      ->fields('freq', ['frequency_text'])
      ->orderBy("sched.next_reminder_timestamp", "ASC")
      ->condition('sched.active', '1')
      ->condition('sched.completed', '1', '<>')
      ->condition('sched.next_reminder_timestamp', $this->today_timestamp, '>');
    return $reminders_forecast_query->range(0, 10)->execute()->fetchAll();
  }
}
```

Since I cannot use Ultimate Cron I want to use the Cron in my linux server. How do I fire off this service via Cron?

I've been reading the [doc](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes) but I'm not getting what they want me to do here. I tried this

```
rmdrs.servicetest:
  path: '/service-test'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\rmdrs\Service\SendRMDRSService::collectAndSend'
  arguments: ['@database', '@plugin.manager.mail', '@language_manager']
  requirements:
    _permission: 'TRUE'
```

But I continue to get an error. Here is what I am getting:

ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\rmdrs\Service\SendRMDRSService::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/jobes/Websites/int-apps/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php on line 31 and exactly 3 expected in Drupal\rmdrs\Service\SendRMDRSService->__construct() (line 28 of /Users/jobes/Websites/int-apps/web/modules/custom/rmdrs/src/Service/SendRMDRSService.php).

Can I get some guidance in this?

Comment: Why don’t you create a Drush command?

Comment: What is this Drush command that you speak of, and how do you use it to specify a file, day, and time? I'm old-school. Used to the writing jobs via the server Cron, pointing to a URL or a PHP file. No expert at Cron by any stretch. Thanks.

Comment: You said you want to schedule a job with system cron. Write a Drush command (much documentation on that is available) and execute the command with system cron whenever you like.

Comment: Are you saying to manually execute Cron? If so, no, I want Mondays at 5am. This module sends out an email to people weekly. I don't want them being sent emails out of nowhere.

Comment: You can create a drush command similar to this and add that command to shell script and run it periodically with linux cron https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3103712/-/blob/8.x-dev/command_examples/src/Commands/DrushCommandExample.php?ref_type=heads

Comment: You can do “weekly” with hook_cron as you know the time of day and can even calculate intervals, for example: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21announcements_feed%21announcements_feed.module/function/announcements_feed_cron/10

Answer (score 0):

To use *rmdrs.send_reminder_service* as controller, the route should use the following line.

```yaml
  _controller: 'rmdrs.send_reminder_service:collectAndSend'
```

The first part of the string is the service ID as used in the .services.yml file, not the class name; that is followed by `:` (not `::`) and by the method name.
The definition of a route does not use any `arguments` line, even when the controller is implemented as service.

A service class does not need to implement `create()`, which is never called from Drupal core when the service instance is created. Drupal core reads the arguments to pass to the class constructor from the .services.yml file.

If I needed to implement a route that is called from the server's cron, I would rather do like the System module does: I would implement a controller (not a service) that calls the necessary service (*rmdrs.send_reminder_service*, in your case). That is similar to what the controller class associated to the *system.cron* route ([`CronController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21CronController.php/class/CronController/9)) does.

```yaml
system.cron:
  path: '/cron/{key}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\CronController::run'
  options:
    no_cache: TRUE
  requirements:
    _access_system_cron: 'TRUE'
```

Notice that the *system.cron* route uses a custom access handler and expects a `key` parameter (which is used from that custom access handler, and should be considered a private key) to avoid the route is used in DOS/DDOS attacks. Only when `key` is equal to the value returned from `\Drupal::state()->get('system.cron_key')`, the controller will invoke the cron service (implemented from the [`Cron`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/class/Cron/9) class).

I would follow this path only if implementing `hook_cron()` would not work for your case, for example because you want your code to be executed every 10 minutes, but you still want `hook_cron()` implementations to be invoked once every 24 hours. In most of the cases, `hook_cron()` is the way to go.

As alternative to implement a controller as you do, you could simply implement [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_cron/9) with code that calls *rmdrs.send_reminder_service* methods. Since you want to execute your code on every Monday, the code should first check that condition is verified (as cron tasks are suggested to run at least once per day).